# How can I install a VSCode extension twice?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have found an extension with two modes, but I want to have both active at the same time. Apart from opening an issue in the repo, which is archived, the only way I can think of to do this is to install two instances of the extension and have both running.

I have tried duplicating the extension folder in `~/.vscode/extensions` and saving it under a different name, but this doesn't appear to work.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: My guess is that there's a good reason why both can't be enabled (they might be conflicting in some way in the code) and that even if you could duplicate the extension, you'd run into issues.

Comment: how is the mode selected? If it is a setting you need to change the code to use a different base-name for the the settings and extension name, and .....